# BeautifulSoup4: find_all() overwrites previous dataset instead of displaying all data targeted

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this webpage: https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E8%AE%80%E9%80%9A%E9%91%92%E8%AB%96/%E5%8D%B701

Code:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

webpages=['https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E8%AE%80%E9%80%9A%E9%91%92%E8%AB%96/%E5%8D%B701']

for item in webpages:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    data = r.get(item, headers=headers)
    data.encoding = 'utf-8'
    page_soup = soup(data.text, 'html5lib')
    headline = page_soup.find_all(class_='mw-headline')
    for el in headline:
        headline_text = el.get_text()
    p = page_soup.find_all('p')
    for el in p:
        p_text = el.get_text()
    text = headline_text + p_text
    with open(r'sample_srape.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(text)
        file.close()
```

The output txt file only displays the last set of the `headline_text + p_text` dataset. It seems like whenever new data is retrieved, it overwrites the previous set of data. How can I make it stop overwriting previous data and display every set of data that is targeted?

Comment: I changed open() from write mode to append mode; the same problem persists

Comment: I note that you are doing two for loops where because of indentation you will only work with the last value from the loop in both cases.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my for loops too. Can you more specific about how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `a` for append in args.

I would expect your indentation to be different in inner two for loops so you are not using just the last item matched each time. Session can be used if more than one request is going to be made - efficiency gain from re-using connection.

Also, a concatenation of paragraphs under a given headline. Slighter clearer variable naming in some parts.

You don't need to `close` as that is handled by `with`. Perhaps, something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

webpages=['https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E8%AE%80%E9%80%9A%E9%91%92%E8%AB%96/%E5%8D%B701']
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

with requests.Session() as s:

    for link in webpages:
        data = s.get(link, headers=headers)
        data.encoding = 'utf-8'
        page_soup = soup(data.text, 'html5lib')
        headlines = page_soup.find_all(class_='mw-headline')

        with open(r'sample_scrape.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:

            for headline in headlines:
                headline_text = headline.get_text()
                paragraphs = page_soup.find_all('p')
                text = ''

                for paragraph in paragraphs:
                    paragraph_text = paragraph.get_text()
                    text+= paragraph_text

                text = headline_text + text
                file.write(text)
```

Comment: I suspect I will need your feedback to tailor this appropriately